# How can I run my function only after a key is pressed?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I want to run the `startDraw()` function when I press a key, and have it run constantly after the key is pressed. I tried to use the `if(mouseIsPressed)` statement, and the `mousePressed()` function that is predefined in p5.js, however it only runs the `startDraw()` function for less than 1 second (the time that the key is pressed).

```js
function draw(){
    background(220);

    startDraw();
}
```

For instance:

```js
function draw(){

    if (mouseIsPressed) {
        startDraw();
    }
}
```

This only works for the duration of the period that a key is pressed, not afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a state variable (`drawing`) which is initialized `False` and set it `True` in the [`mousePressed()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mousePressed) callback:

```js
let drawing = False;

function draw(){
      background(220);

      if (drawing) {
          startDraw();
      }
}

function mousePressed() {
    drawing = True;
}
```

---

Alternatively you can start the application with the execution of `draw()` stopped, by [`noLoop()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/noLoop) and start it by [`loop()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loop) when the mouse is pressed:

```js
function setup() {

    // [...]

    noLoop();
}   

function mousePressed() {
    loop();
}

function draw(){
    background(220);
    startDraw();
}
```